# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have one drop down image with one text field , uipicker. So when user press text field - uipicker will open to select the value and one done button will be there for uipicker. When user press that uipicker done button selected data will be added to text field value.

But i have added one image view at right corner of textfield. When user press text field and when uipicker open , that uiimageview will rotate upside and down. And when user press done button, that imageview will come normla postion.

Butthe problem is, my done action button is in seperate nsobject class.And my uiimage view in one view controller. What i did is ?. I just call the view controller uiimage view to nsobject class and i am making the image rotation.

But its crashing when i press done button .

Here my code in view controller :

```
    lazy var ctDataPicker = CTDataPickerplayer()
         @IBOutlet weak var sportsDropImage: UIImageView!

            @IBOutlet weak var hobbiesDropImage: UIImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                ctDataPicker.hobimage? = hobbiesDropImage as UIImageView!
                ctDataPicker.spoimage? = sportsDropImage as UIImageView!



            }

extension CricketFanViewController:UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {


        selectedText = textField

       if  textField == Experience {

        hobbiesDropImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14)
        sportsDropImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)


            ctDataPicker = CTDataPickerplayer()
            let indexPos = Hobbeies.indexOf(Experience.text!) ?? 0
            ctDataPicker.showPicker(self, inputText: textField, data: Hobbeies,selectedValueIndex: indexPos)
        }
        else if  textField == playedTeam{


        hobbiesDropImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
        sportsDropImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14)


            ctDataPicker = CTDataPickerplayer()
            let indexPos = Sports.indexOf(playedTeam.text!) ?? 0
            ctDataPicker.showPicker(self, inputText: textField, data: Sports, selectedValueIndex: indexPos)
        }
    }
}
```

My NSObject class code:

```
  import Foundation

    import SwiftCountryPicker

    class CTDataPickerplayer: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

        var dataPicker: UIPickerView!
        var inputText:UITextField!
        var parent:UIViewController!
        var pickerData: [String]!
        var feetStr = String()
        var inchStr = String()


        var hobimage:UIImageView!
        var spoimage:UIImageView!
    func showPicker(parent:UIViewController,inputText:UITextField, data: [String], selectedValueIndex: Int){

        self.inputText = inputText
        self.parent = parent
        self.pickerData = data

        if dataPicker == nil {
            dataPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,parent.view.frame.size.width, 216))
            dataPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            dataPicker.dataSource = self
            dataPicker.delegate = self
            dataPicker.selectRow(selectedValueIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            _selectedValue = self.pickerData.count > 0 ? self.pickerData[selectedValueIndex] : ""
        }
        inputText.inputView = dataPicker

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "B12420")
        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CTDataPickerplayer.doneClick))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CTDataPickerplayer.cancelClick))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        inputText.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    }


        func doneClick() {


            hobimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
            spoimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)

    }
```

My app crash in done action button  code here :

> hobimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
>               spoimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)

Comment: Where did you initialize `hobimage`?

Comment: Initialize ?? .. In nsobject class or ??

Comment: Better post your complete code with separate class name as you defined.

Comment: Why did you declare the properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Comment: @Santosh  Please check my poast, in viwecontroller thats all code and also in my nsobject class

Comment: @EricAya  i din get u ??

Comment: How do you create an instance of SwiftCountryPicker, and how do you set the `hobimage` and `spoimage` properties?

Comment: @DuncanC  i want to use the `sportsDropImage`, `hobbiesDropImage` in my nsobject class under done action method. IF I AM WRONG. Can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: Third and final time. Edit your question to show how you create an instance of your SwiftCountryPicker object, how you set the `hobimage` and `spoimage` properties, and how you're invoking its `doneClick()` function

Comment: Where do you set `image` for `hobbiesDropImage`? Do you have an image before you start rotating it?

Comment: @Santosh  yes, i just place one uiimage view in the screen via storyboard. And i make an ibloutlet. that name only `hobbiesDropImage`. And first time when user press textfield , uipicker will open adn image will flip. And when user press done button in uipicker image have to go to normal position

Comment: @Santosh  check my post

Answer (score 1):

You made `hobimage` and `spoimage` "implicitly unwrapped optionals (Type `UIImageView!`.)

Think of the `!` operator as the "crash if nil" operator. Any time you reference an implicitly unwrapped optional and it's nil, you crash.

Therefore either `hobimage` or `spoimage` is probably nil. You probably forgot to connect the outlets in Interface builder.

Comment: hobimage, spoimage  i can not keep as iboutlet in my nsobject class

Comment: Edit your question to show the init method of your NSObject class, as well as the code that creates an instance of that class and invokes the doneClick method

Comment: What about the second part of my comment: "...show ... the code that creates an instance of that class and invokes the doneClick method "

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `ctDataPicker`, you have it initialized lazily at the top of your `vc` and assigning your `imageViews` in `viewDidLoad`. Now again you are intiailizing same object in your `extension CricketFanViewController:UITextFieldDelegate`

```
            ctDataPicker = CTDataPickerplayer()
            let indexPos = Sports.indexOf(playedTeam.text!) ?? 0
            ctDataPicker.showPicker(self, inputText: textField, data: Sports, selectedValueIndex: indexPos)
```

Please check here and decide what is your requirement.

Comment: i changed that, but still crash on same line

Comment: @Santhosh   i am getting same crash. Can you tell me how can i call that image view in my view controller to my nobject class

Comment: Just remove this line `ctDataPicker = CTDataPickerplayer()`

Comment: I DID, but still i got that same crash